# remove duplicates with specific criteria sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am recording the changes made in a directory. That directory has a lot of files so I am trying to reduce the size of my database by deleting duplicates. But to make things clear let me show you what I have.

I have a table named table1

[image]

from looking at this table I can tell that the first time I scanned the directory I had two Files A and B. The next time I scanned the directory I know that I have added file C and modified file A by looking at the table. note that file A has a different DateModified that's why I can tel it's been modified. Lastly on my last scan I know that file X has been created and also that file B has been modified. File A and C stayed the same.

After creating a lot of scans there are several files that get repeated. If they have a different DateModified I don't want to remove duplicates because I want to track changes on that directory. Moreover when removing duplicates I want to stay with the lower DateInserted so that I can know when it was modifies.

So in other words I want to build a query where I can remove FileID 6 because FileID 3 contains the same path and same DateModified. I will also like to remove FileID 4 because fileID 2 cointains the same two records. And lastly I will like to remove fileID 5 for the same reason. How could I build this query?

EDIT

I am just adding the query that I have been working with hoping it can help.

[image]

with this query I know that those are the files that repeat based on the criteria that I need. I don't know how to go from there and delete the higher dateInserted duplicated based on those results. Hope this helps

Comment: Means ... you want to remove all the filedID where Path and DateModified is same. right?

Comment: yeah and I want to keep the one which has the lower dateInserted

Comment: I been playing around with it and I have interested result I will edit my question hope those comments can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want unique records where a unique record qualifies as a distinct Path & DateModified combination, and when duplicates occur you want the earliest record returned.

This query should hopefully do the trick:
SELECT MIN(FileID) AS FileID,Path,datemodified,dateInserted FROM table1 GROUP BY Path,DateModified

Comment: yeah that does the trick but how could I actually make the table look like that instead of just selecting. I want to delete the records from the database. the reason why I am doing that is to shrink the database size.

Comment: Maybe I need to select the opposite of what you got then delete all the records included in that. How could I do that?

Comment: Delete from table1
where FileID NOT IN( 
 SELECT MIN(FileID) AS FileID FROM table1 GROUP BY Path,DateModified
)

Comment: I would 1) Duplicate your table structure (call it table2) 2) Insert the records into table2 using the query above 3) Add a UNIQUE key to Path,DateModified to prevent any more duplication creeping in again.

Comment: You may also want to try ALTER IGNORE table1 ADD UNIQUE (Path,DateModified) ... This would create a UNIQUE key on the original table and delete duplicates as it encounters them.